# How can I do type checking in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

The example here

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Provides the following code

```
var story1 = new Story({
      title: "A man who cooked Nintendo"
    , _creator: aaron._id
  });
```

_creator is defined above as follows

```
_creator : { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Person' }
```

If I modify the code to the following

```
  var story1 = new Story({
      title: "A man who cooked Nintendo"
    , _creator: {name: 'test'}
  });
```

It seems to happily insert the data into MongoDB.

```
{ "title" : "A man who cooked Nintendo", "_creator" : { "name" : "test" }, "_id" : ObjectId("4fb7a55315c5f2de07000002"), "fans" : [ ] }
```

How would I catch the error before insertion? I would like to check that it is not only an ObjectId but also that it corresponds to a valid Person.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To continue what @JohnnyHK proposed, here is a complete solution(assuming _creator is a reference to a numeric id).

If you want to check if the value is a valid ObjectId

```
function isObjectId(n) {
  return mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(n);
}
```

validate: [validator, 'my error type']

```
_creator : { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Person', validate: isObjectId }
```

Comment: this gives `TypeError: Object function ObjectId(key, options) {   SchemaType.call(this, key, options, 'ObjectID');
} has no method 'isValid'`

Comment: I believe they've changed it to:
 
`mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid()`

Answer (score 6):

The method isValid does not exist (anymore?), your best bet is a simple regular expression, as provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985228/mongodb-node-check-if-objectid-is-valid)

Comment: I believe they've changed it to:
 
`mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid()`

Answer (score 1):

You could add validation to the _creator field of the schema as described [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html).

```
_creator : { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Person', validate: ... }
```