# Can I determine if a string is a MongoDB ObjectID?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, coffeescript, express

I am doing MongoDB lookups by converting a string to BSON. Is there a way for me to determine if the string I have is a valid ObjectID for Mongo before doing the conversion?

Here is the coffeescript for my current findByID function. It works great, but I'd like to lookup by a different attribute if I determine the string is not an ID.

```
db.collection "pages", (err, collection) ->
  collection.findOne
    _id: new BSON.ObjectID(id)
  , (err, item) ->
    if item
      res.send item
    else
      res.send 404
```

Answer (score 243, accepted):

I found that the mongoose ObjectId validator works to validate valid objectIds but I found a few cases where invalid ids were considered valid. (eg: any 12 characters long string)

```
var ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId;
ObjectId.isValid('microsoft123'); //true
ObjectId.isValid('timtomtamted'); //true
ObjectId.isValid('551137c2f9e1fac808a5f572'); //true
```

What has been working for me is casting a string to an objectId and then checking that the original string matches the string value of the objectId.

```
new ObjectId('timtamtomted'); //616273656e6365576f726b73
new ObjectId('537eed02ed345b2e039652d2') //537eed02ed345b2e039652d2
```

This work because valid ids do not change when casted to an ObjectId but a string that gets a false valid will change when casted to an objectId.

Comment: Theoretically you could add these two methods to generate a pretty damn good ObjectID validator, will get that done today.

Comment: So, something like this? ```function checkObjectIdValid(id){
    if(ObjectID.isValid(id)){
        if(new ObjectID(id) === id){
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    } else {
        return false
    }
}```

Comment: Something like that would work, or string comparison using ObjetcId’s toString function.

Comment: But if you got bad input which is not 12 length and contains special keys? You will get an error by the time you will do `ObjectId(INPUT)`. I think it better to wrap the validation using try and catch function.

Comment: Actually @JacksonVaughan answer is almost right. It was missing a String() to convert the new ObjectID(id) to a string since we are comparing it with another string. Here is the complete right answer:

`const ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId;

function isObjectIdValid(id) { 
  if (ObjectId.isValid(id)) {
    if (String(new ObjectId(id)) === id) { 
      return true 
    } else { 
      return false 
    } 
  } else { 
    return false 
  } 
}`

Comment: @marcvander let me `es6`ify that for you: `isObjectIdValid = id => ObjectId.isValid(id) ? String(new ObjectId(id) === id) ? true : false : false;`

Comment: Standard function exists now (isValidObjectId), check my answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/61779949/11896312

Comment: Explanation to [why 12 characters can be correct id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58279842/how-is-a-mongodb-objectid-12-bytes).

Comment: @marcvander why use `String()` when the resulting ObjectId instance has a `toString()` method?

Comment: Let me add my function too with native MongoDB driver, as the others didn't work for me:  

`try { return id.toString() === new ObjectId(id).toString(); } catch (err) { return false; }`

Answer (score 119):

### ✅ Build In Solution `isValidObjectId()` > Mongoose 5.7.12

If you are using Mongoose, we can test whether a String is of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters by using **mongoose build-in** [isValidObjectId](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/mongoose.html#mongoose_Mongoose-isValidObjectId).

**This is SUFFICIENT to perform a valid query without throwing any invalid object id errors**

```
mongoose.isValidObjectId(string); /* will return true/false */
```

---

##### DO NOTE!

`isValidObjectId()` is most commonly used to test a expected objectID, in order to avoid mongoose throwing invalid object ID error.

Example

```
if (mongoose.isValidObjectId("some 12 byte string")) {
     return collection.findOne({ _id: "some 12 byte string" })
     // returns null if no record found.
}
```

If you do not conditionally test whether expected objectID is valid, you will need to catch the error.

```
try {
  return collection.findOne({ _id: "abc" }) 
  //this will throw error
} catch(error) {
  console.log('invalid _id error', error)
}
```

Since `findOne({ _id: null })` and `findOne({ _id: undefined })` are completely valid queries (doesn't throw error), `isValidObjectId(undefined)` and `isValidObjectId(null)` will return true.

##### DO NOTE 2!

**123456789012** may not appear to look like a bson string but it's completely a valid ObjectID because the following query **does not** throw error. (return null if no record found).

```
findOne({ _id: ObjectId('123456789012')}) // ✅ valid query
```

**313233343536373839303132** may appear to look like a 24 character string (it's the hex value of **123456789012**), but it's also a valid ObjectId because the following query **does not** throw error. (return null if no record found)

```
findOne({ _id: ObjectId('313233343536373839303132')}) // ✅ valid query
```

The following are invalid (1 string char less than above examples)

```
findOne({ _id: ObjectId('12345678901')}) // ❌ not 12 byte string
findOne({ _id: ObjectId('31323334353637383930313')}) // ❌ not 24 char hex
```

### Format of ObjectId

ObjectIds are small, likely unique, fast to generate, and ordered. ObjectId values are 12 bytes in length, consisting of:

- a 4-byte timestamp value, representing the ObjectId's creation, measured in seconds since the Unix epoch
- a 5-byte **random value** generated once per process. This **random value** is unique to the machine and process.
- a 3-byte incrementing counter, initialized to a random value

Due to the above **random value**, ObjectId **cannot be calculated**. It can only appear to be a 12 byte string, or 24 character hex string.

Comment: seriously, let's vote this thing up. The old accepted answer was great when the library provided no support for this, but now it does. To bypass it is a hack that depends on implementation details.

Comment: This is accepting any random number of character length 12 as a valid object id. Is there any way to check only for object IDs with 24 characters that too in an accepted format i.e.  alphanumeric? By accepted format this is what is meant like described here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/

Comment: notice there is a random 5 byte value in the objectId. More often than not, `isValidObjectId` is more than sufficient since your queries will not be rejected by mongoose. If it's a invalid ObjectId, mongoose will throw error if your schema requires objectid. Checking for validObjectID is to reject the query before your mongoose throw the error.

Comment: take into account that this function returns true if the input is undefined. This may not be what you want.

Comment: Yes and No. `undefined` can be treated as a valid ObjectID simply because if you do `Model.find({ _id: undefined})`, it will not throw an error. While if you do `Model.find({ _id: 'abc'})` (invalid ObjectID), it will throw a **Cast to ObjectId failed** error

Comment: This string - how-fit-am-i - is being returned as true.
Can anyone explain why that might be?

Comment: it’s is valid because error will not be thrown by your mongoose validation should you use ObjectId as the field type. It will simply return null if no results are found. If you were to use a shorter/longer string, your query will throw error which need to be caught by your try/catch block.

Comment: Sadly it validates `undefined` and `null`

Comment: this is correct behavior, because `findOne({ _id: undefined})` should not throw an error. undefined and null are valid values. You may refer to https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/a8a615cf89ffe65d3145aaeb1d64df8887eb105d/lib/index.js#L957 where it intentionally returns true on null

Comment: Still returns true for stuff like `microsoft123` and `Manajemenfs2`

Comment: It's true because it's a string of 12 characters and `findOne({_id: ObjectId('microsoft123')})` will return null (if record does not exist) instead of throwing error.

Comment: added explanation on why it's true in answer.

Answer (score 103):

You can use a regular expression to test for that:

CoffeeScript

```coffee
if id.match /^[0-9a-fA-F]{24}$/
    # it's an ObjectID
else
    # nope
```

JavaScript

```js
if (id.match(/^[0-9a-fA-F]{24}$/)) {
    // it's an ObjectID    
} else {
    // nope    
}
```

Comment: Hmm this could match non-objectIds as well, best way is to either build a validator based on the spec and regex it's specific parts or try to make a new objectid and house a catch block to catch if it can do it.

Comment: @Sammaye It's the same validation that's used by the [BSON ObjectID constructor](https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson/blob/master/lib/bson/objectid.js#L15).  Can you give me an example of a non-ObjectID string it would match?

Comment: Wow, I didn't see that coming. Well any 24 character string that has numbers and letters in, i.e. `lol456712bbfghLLsdfr`

Comment: @Sammaye The regex only matches alpha chars a-f and A-F so that string wouldn't match.

Comment: Well ok maybe I wrote that a little fast so: `456546576541232123adcdeA` would then match

Comment: @Sammaye But that's a valid ObjectID, so it should match.

Comment: see comments [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11989159/645458) regarding the same

Comment: Probably the right way, officially suggested by mongoose https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/1959#issuecomment-97457325

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, this is what is officially suggested by the folks at mongoose.

Answer (score 20):

I have used the native node mongodb driver to do this in the past. The isValid method checks that the value is a valid BSON ObjectId. [See the documentation here.](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/objectid.html#objectid-isvalid)

```
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
console.log( ObjectID.isValid(12345) );
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work, above returns true for a random number.

Comment: I think that's most likely because it should be `ObjectId`, not `ObjectID`. :)

Comment: this should be accepted answer, no need for mongoose

Comment: I think this answer is quite old... The only thing I could find in the latest version is this one: [https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/5.3/classes/BSON.ObjectId.html#isValid](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/5.3/classes/BSON.ObjectId.html#isValid), but I get the same issue as @DanOchiana, passing it a number number it returns `true`

Answer (score 6):

mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(string) always returns True if string contains 12 letters

```
let firstUserID = '5b360fdea392d731829ded18';
let secondUserID = 'aaaaaaaaaaaa';

console.log(mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(firstUserID)); // true
console.log(mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(secondUserID)); // true

let checkForValidMongoDbID = new RegExp("^[0-9a-fA-F]{24}$");
console.log(checkForValidMongoDbID.test(firstUserID)); // true
console.log(checkForValidMongoDbID.test(secondUserID)); // false
```

Answer (score 3):

Below is a function that both checks with the ObjectId `isValid` method and whether or not `new ObjectId(id)` returns the same value. The reason for `isValid` not being enough alone is described very well by Andy Macleod in the chosen answer.

```
const ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId;

/**
 * True if provided object ID valid
 * @param {string} id 
 */
function isObjectIdValid(id){ 
  return ObjectId.isValid(id) && new ObjectId(id) == id;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the review. I updated the description

Comment: This won't work as you are doing a strict comparison between the string and object id. Please update to double equals.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to check if the string is a valid Mongo ObjectId is using **mongodb** module.

```
const ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

if(ObjectID.isValid(777777777777777)){
   console.log("Valid ObjectID")
}
```

Comment: It's nuts how popular Mongoose is.  The core mongodb driver is more powerful and in newer versions with POJO support Mongoose is just a layer of inefficiency.

Comment: Yes. In fact, native mongo query functions are way more faster than using mongoose functions.

Comment: this method has bug, even on passing invalid objectIds it returns true
https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/objectid-isvalid-returns-true-for-non-object-ids/164284

Answer (score 3):

Mongoose 6.2.5 introduces [`mongoose.isObjectIdOrHexString()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#mongoose_Mongoose-isObjectIdOrHexString) which returns `true` only if the given value is an `ObjectId` instance or a 24 character hex string representing an `ObjectId`, and will return `false` for numbers, documents, and strings of length 12 (unlike [`mongoose.isValidObjectId()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#mongoose_Mongoose-isValidObjectId) which is just a wrapper for `mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid()` in Mongoose 6)

> **Mongoose.prototype.isObjectIdOrHexString()**
>
> **Parameters**
>
> - v «Any»
>
> Returns true if the given value is a Mongoose ObjectId (using instanceof) or if the given value is a 24 character hex string, which is the most commonly used string representation of an ObjectId.
>
> This function is similar to isValidObjectId(), but considerably more strict, because isValidObjectId() will return true for any value that Mongoose can convert to an ObjectId. That includes Mongoose documents, any string of length 12, and any number. isObjectIdOrHexString() returns true only for ObjectId instances or 24 character hex strings, and will return false for numbers, documents, and strings of length 12.
>
> **Example**:
>
> ```
> mongoose.isObjectIdOrHexString(new mongoose.Types.ObjectId()); // true
> mongoose.isObjectIdOrHexString('62261a65d66c6be0a63c051f'); // true
>
> mongoose.isObjectIdOrHexString('0123456789ab'); // false
> mongoose.isObjectIdOrHexString(6); // false
> mongoose.isObjectIdOrHexString(new User({ name: 'test' })); // false
> mongoose.isObjectIdOrHexString({ test: 42 }); // false
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Here is some code I have written based on @andy-macleod's answer.

It can take either an int or string or ObjectId and returns a valid ObjectId if the passed value is valid or null if it is invalid:

```
var ObjectId= require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId;

function toObjectId(id) {

    var stringId = id.toString().toLowerCase();

    if (!ObjectId.isValid(stringId)) {
        return null;
    }

    var result = new ObjectId(stringId);
    if (result.toString() != stringId) {
        return null;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The only way i found is to create a new ObjectId with the value i want to check, if the input is equal to the output, the id is valid :

```
function validate(id) {
    var valid = false;
    try
    {
        if(id == new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(""+id))
           valid = true;

    }
    catch(e)
    {
       valid = false;
    }
    return valid;
}

> validate(null)
false
> validate(20)
false
> validate("abcdef")
false
> validate("5ad72b594c897c7c38b2bf71")
true
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is basically wrap your ObjectId method in a try and catch service.
Then you are using this service to handle Objecet Id's, instead of using the method directly:

```
var ObjectId = REQUIRE OR IMPORT ...

// service
function oid(str) {
 try {   
   return ObjectId(str);
 } catch(err) {
   return false;
 }
}

// usage
if (oid(USER_INPUT)) {
  // continue
} else {
  // throw error
}
```

You can also send null or empty props to get a new generated ID.

Answer (score 1):

@ross-u answer is just amazing.

I have chained the methods to do a full validation inline:

```
documentId = id && isValid(id) && new ObjectId(id) == id ? id : null
```

Note the double equal sign, which is VERY important as `new ObjectId()` does not return a string and strict comparison will return false when compared against a normal string (which I had coming in my logic).

The methods have been destructured from the `mongoose` object exposed by the require:

```
const {
  Types: {
    ObjectId: { isValid },
    ObjectId
  }
} = require("mongoose");
```

Answer (score 1):

This approach may help somebody. It works with nodejs mongodb driver

```
if (ObjectId.isValid(stringId) && (ObjectId(stringId).toString() === stringId)){
  // your operation
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be using the `validator` library which comes with a `isMongoId` option to validate if the string is indeed in a format of the MongoDB ObjectId. [check out the docs](https://github.com/validatorjs/validator.js).

Here's a sample implementation:

```js
import validator from 'validator';

const checkValidID = (id) => validator.isMongoId(id);

// checkValidId('Any valid object ID') returns true 
// checkValidId('The Warships') returns false
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the hex string you can use this:

```
ObjectId.isValid(ObjectId.createFromHexString(hexId));
```

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while to get a valid solution as the one proposed by @Andy Macleod of comparing objectId value with its own string was crashing the Express.js server on:

```
var view_task_id_temp=new mongodb.ObjectID("invalid_id_string"); //this crashed
```

I just used a simple try catch to solve this.

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var id_error=false;
try{
    var x=new mongodb.ObjectID("57d9a8b310b45a383a74df93");
    console.log("x="+JSON.stringify(x));
}catch(err){
    console.log("error="+err);
    id_error=true;
}

if(id_error==false){
   // Do stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For mongoose , Use isValid() function to check if objectId is valid or not

Example :

```
var ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;
if(ObjectId.isValid(req.params.documentId)){
   console.log('Object id is valid'); 
}else{
   console.log('Invalid Object id');
}
```

Comment: This solution will evaluate to true the strings that begin with a hex digit and have a right length, such as `"comfort12345"`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29231016/6375464) of Andy Macleod, I created a helper function that can be used to check both strings and ObjectId's.

#### Implentation:

```js
var ObjectId = require("mongoose").Types.ObjectId;


function isValidObjectId(value) {
  // If value is an ObjectId cast it to a string to allow
  // passing string or ObjectId as an argument.
  var valueString = typeof value === "string" ? value : String(value); 
  
  // Cast the string to ObjectId
  var idInstance = new ObjectId(valueString); 

  return String(idInstance) === valueString;
}
```

#### Explanation:

In the accepted answer **Andy Macleod** said:

> What has been working for me is casting a string to an objectId and
> then checking that the original string matches the string value of the
> objectId.

**With Invalid ObjectId string**

Casting an invalid string (like `"microsoft"`) to ObjectId, gives a completely different value:

```js
        "microsoft"
            ↓
String( new ObjectId("microsoft")  );
            ↓
"6d6963726f736f6674313233"
            ↓
"microsoft" === "6d6963726f736f6674313233" // false
```

**With Valid ObjectId string**

Casting a valid string like (`"6d6963726f736f6674313233"`) to ObjectId, gives the same value:

```js
"6d6963726f736f6674313233"
            ↓
String( new ObjectId("6d6963726f736f6674313233") )
            ↓
"6d6963726f736f6674313233"     
            ↓
"6d6963726f736f6674313233" === "6d6963726f736f6674313233"  // true
```

Answer (score 0):

https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/objectid.html#objectid-isvalid

From MongoDB documentation:

Constructor documentation:

```
ObjectID()
Constructor
Create a new ObjectID instance

class ObjectID()
    Arguments:  
        id (string) – Can be a 24 byte hex string, 12 byte binary string or a Number.
    Returns:    
        object instance of ObjectID.
```

ObjectId.isValid() documentation:

```
Checks if a value is a valid bson ObjectId

ObjectID.isValid()
    Returns:    boolean return true if the value is a valid bson ObjectId, return false otherwise.
```

So, `isValid(...)` will return true if argument is a valid BSON ObjectId object, and the constructor `ObjectId(...)` only accepts a valid BSON ObjectId object argument (Basically, `isValid(...)` will return false if an exception will be thrown by constructor).

Knowing this. We can first check if argument is a valid `ObjectId`, and then create an `ObjectId` with that value and compare HEX strings.

```
const objectId = 'str_object_id';
const isValid = ObjectId.isValid(objectId) && new ObjectId(objectId).toHexString() == objectId;
```

If passed `objectId` is not a valid `ObjectId` HEX string (it has not been converted by constructor), this method will return false.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a function exported by a mongo db driver or ORM, you can do some simple objectId validation using this RegExp:

```
/[0-9a-f]{24}/i
```

Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73464785/how-to-implement-mongodb-objectid-validation-from-scratch/73465274#73465274) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

For plain javscript, this is helpful:

```
const isMongoId = str => {
    return str.match(/^[0-9a-fA-F]{24}$/);
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution **without mongoose**

```js
import {ObjectId} from 'bson';

ObjectId.isValid(value);
```

Answer (score -3):

Warning: **isValid** will return **true** for arbitrary 12/24 length strings beginning with a valid hex digit.
Currently I think this is a better check:

> `((thing.length === 24 || thing.length === 12) && isNaN(parseInt(thing,16)) !== true)`

Comment: This would evaluate to `true` for `'funky string'`. Any string that's the right length and starts with a hex digit will satisfy it.