# How could I check if it's a String object of 12 bytes, ObjectID in mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, string, mongodb

I'd like to check for a correct ObjectID to continue my code. I'am on NodeJS and I don't want to get the error:

> Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters

Actually I got those tests:

```
if (!user.id || !user.id.match("/^[0-9a-fA-f]{24}$") || !typeof(user.id) === 'string') {
        console.log("user id is required !")
        return callback("user id is required !")
    }
```

For string of 24 hex characters I got this regex :

```
!user.id.match("/^[0-9a-fA-f]{24}$")
```

And I am searching for check if it is a string of 12 bytes :

```
!typeof(user.id) === 'string'
```

How should I add the verification for the 12 bytes?

Any idea please?

Comment: Check out https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/1959

Comment: Are you really asking us "how do you check a string is 12 characters long"?

Comment: I am asking for both in a same test @TomLord

Comment: @Cupkek05 `^(.{12}|[0-9a-fA-f]{24})$`??...

Comment: @TomLord, thanks, it works, sorry I am new with regex... It is not so simple to understand :/

Comment: hhm.. I still got the Error when I am passing a wrong Id, I don't get it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With NodeJS if you are using :

```
const objectID = require('mongodb').objectID
```

You could simply test your ObjectID like that :

```
ObjectID.isValid(yourobjectid)
```

It will return true if it is valid and false if it is not.

Answer (score 1):

From what I see you can pass as an Id any string you want. You should
probably turn it into Hexadecimal string first (http://forums.devshed.com/javascript-development-115/convert-string-hex-674138.html)

```
function toHex(str) {
   var hex = '';
   for(var i=0;i<str.length;i++) {
      hex += ''+str.charCodeAt(i).toString(16);
   }
   return hex;
}
```

and then create an ObjectId from the Hexadecimal string the way it is suggested from the mongoDB Documentation (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/)

**Specify a Hexadecimal string**

To generate a new ObjectId using ObjectId() with a unique hexadecimal string:

```
y = ObjectId("507f191e810c19729de860ea")
```

Comment: ObjectID are created by themselves when I am creating a user. Actually, I am checking if the user is registered before inserting an object. my URL need the ObjectID of the user to insert an object. I would like to check if the ObjectID passed in the URL is a correct ObjectID or not. I don't want to create ObjectID by myself with your Hex method :)

Comment: Maybe this post is what you need? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13850819/can-i-determine-if-a-string-is-a-mongodb-objectid

Comment: Ye maybe but it is possible to check that just with a regex ? It will have to match if it's a string of 24 hex characters or a single string of 12 bytes. Those validations must be possible with regex I guess...