# mongoose Model.findById not returning null when document is not found

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

When the document with the given id is not found, the catch block gets executed.
But when document is not found, then findById returns null and so it should send 404 and not 500 status code.

```
app.get('/users/:id', (req, res) => {
    const _id = req.params.id;

    User.findById(_id).then((user) => {
       if (!user) {
           return res.status(404).send()
       }

       res.send(user)
    }).catch((error) => {
       res.status(500).send()
    })
})
```

Comment: Your query looks good, event i run your code and its working properly, please check other possibilities.

Comment: One possibility is the _id parameter isn't a valid ObjecId, which is expected by the `findById` function. Your problem looks like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67246104/mongoose-defining-404-status-for-not-finding-a-document-doesnt-work/67247073#67247073

Comment: It'd be nice if you could provide the error message in the catch block too.

Comment: @ĐăngKhoaĐinh Thanks a lot, it was happening because of invalid ObjectId. Also thanks to everyone for the response.