# CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "undefined" (type string) at path "_id" for model "Order"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, mongoose, react-redux

I am building a full-stack e-commerce website and using Mongoose, express for the backend part, react, and react-redux for the frontend part. But I got a CastError when I was trying to get the order ID and then redirect clients to their order page after they placed an order.

Created an order successfully and I can see the order ID such as'_id:ObjectID(62d9687e10d97912c576aa6a)' in the MongoDB database[image: MongoDB order data img].
The problem is I can not fetch the order ID properly with this error.

//Error info from the terminal:

```
CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "undefined" (type 
string) at path "_id" for model "Order"
 at model.Query.exec 
 at model.Query.Query.then 
 at processTicksAndRejections 
 (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

//placeOrderPafe.jsx:

```
function PlaceorderPage(props) {

const cart = useSelector((state) => state.cart);

if (!cart.paymentMethod) {
  props.history.push("/payment");
}

const orderCreate = useSelector((state) => state.orderCreate);
const { loading, success, error, order } = orderCreate;


const dispatch = useDispatch();
const placeOrderHandler = () => {
  dispatch(createOrder({ ...cart, orderItems: cart.cartItems 
 }));};

useEffect(() => {
  if (success) {
   props.history.push(`/orders/${order._id}`);
   dispatch({ type: ORDER_CREATE_RESET });
 }
}, [dispatch, order, props.history, success]);

return
  .....}
```

//orderRouter.js:

```
import express from 'express';
import expressAsyncHandler from 'express-async-handler';
import Order from '../models/orderModel.js';
import { isAuth } from '../utils.js';

const orderRouter = express.Router();

orderRouter.post('/',isAuth,
expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
if (req.body.orderItems.length === 0) {
  res.status(400).send({ message: 'Cart is empty' });
} else {
  const order = new Order({
    orderItems: req.body.orderItems,
    shippingAddress: req.body.shippingAddress,
    paymentMethod: req.body.paymentMethod,
    itemsPrice: req.body.itemsPrice,
    shippingPrice: req.body.shippingPrice,
    taxPrice: req.body.taxPrice,
    totalPrice: req.body.totalPrice,
    user: req.user._id,
    });
  const createdOrder = await order.save();
  res
    .status(201)
    .send({ message: 'New Order Created', order: createdOrder 
   });}}));

 orderRouter.get('/:id',isAuth,
    expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
 const order = await Order.findById(req.params.id);
   if (order) {
     res.send(order);
    } else {
    res.status(404).send({ message: 'Order Not Found' });})
    );

   export default orderRouter;
```

//orderModel.js:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const orderSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
     orderItems: [
      {
        name: { type: String, required: true },
        qty: { type: Number, required: true },
        image: { type: String, required: true },
        price: { type: Number, required: true },
        product: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Product",
        required: true,},},],

  shippingAddress: {
    fullName: { type: String, required: true },
    address: { type: String, required: true },
    city: { type: String, required: true },
    zipcode: { type: String, required: true },
    country: { type: String, required: true },
  },
  paymentMethod: { type: String, required: true },
  itemsPrice: { type: Number, required: true },
  shippingPrice: { type: Number, required: true },
  taxPrice: { type: Number, required: true },
  totalPrice: { type: Number, required: true },
  user: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User", 
     required: true },
  isPaid: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  paidAt: { type: Date },
  isDelivered: { type: Boolean, default: false },
   deliveredAt: { type: Date },
    },
  {
   timestamps: true,
   });
  const Order = mongoose.model("Order", orderSchema);
  export default Order;
```

//server.js:

```
dotenv.config();
const mongodbUrl = config.MONGODB_URL;
mongoose
 .connect(mongodbUrl, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useCreateIndex: true,
 })
.catch((error) => console.log(error.reason));

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use("/api/users", userRoute);
app.use("/api/products", productRoute);
app.use("/api/orders", orderRouter);
```

Comment: It could be this line: `const order = await Order.findById(req.params.id);`. Make sure `req.params.id` is a valid id string before using it in `findById` function

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion, do you know how to test if req.params.id is valid or not? Thank you!

Comment: You can see various ways to do this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13850819/can-i-determine-if-a-string-is-a-mongodb-objectid)