# How to implement MongoDB ObjectId validation from scratch?

Tags: mongodb

I'm developing a front-end app where I want to support searching data by the id, so I'm going to have an "object id" field. I want to validate the object id to make sure it's a valid MongoDB ObjectId before sending it to the API.

So I searched on how to do it and I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13850819/can-i-determine-if-a-string-is-a-mongodb-objectid), where all the answers suggest using a implementation provided by a MongoDB driver or ORM such as [mongodb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb) or [mongose](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose). However, I don't want to go that way, because I don't want to install an entire database driver/ORM in my front-end app just to use some id validation - I'd rather implement the validation myself.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find an existing implementation. Then I tried checking the ObjectId spec and implementing the validation myself, but that didn't work out either.

The specification says...

> The ObjectID BSON type is a 12-byte value consisting of three different portions (fields):
>
> - a 4-byte value representing the seconds since the Unix epoch in the highest order bytes,
> - a 5-byte random number unique to a machine and process,
> - a 3-byte counter, starting with a random value.

Which doesn't make much sense to me. When it says the ObjectId has 12 bytes, it makes me think that the string representation is going to have 12 characters (1 byte = 1 char), but it doesn't. Most object ids have 24 characters.

Finally, I searched mongodb's and mongoose's source code but I didn't had much luck with that either. The best I could do was finding [this line of code](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/40fa081a5f081d98cefb742a2dc9deed628a937a/lib/index.js#L1012), but I don't know where to go from there.

**TL;DR:** What is the actual algorithm to check if a given string is a valid MongoDB Object Id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You find is correct, you just stopped too early. the `isValid` comes from the underlying bson library: https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson/blob/a2a81bc1bc63fa5bf3f918fbcaafef25aca2df9d/src/objectid.ts#L297

And yes, you get it right - there is not much to validate. Any 12 bytes can be an object ID. The reason you see 24 characters is because not all 256 ASCII are printable/readable, so the ObjectID is usually presented in hex format - 2 characters per byte. The regexp to validate 12-bytes hex representation would be `/[0-9a-f]{24}/i`

**TL;DR:** check the constructor of ObjectId in the bson library for the official validation algorithm

**Hint:** you don't need most of it, as you are limited to string input on frontend.