# Regex for MongoDB ObjectID

Tags: javascript, regex, mongodb

With reference to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11989159/645458) SO question, I have a scenario where I only need to match a hex string with a-f included. All else should not match. Example:

```
checkForHexRegExp.test("112345679065574883030833"); // => false
checkForHexRegExp.test("FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF"); // => false
checkForHexRegExp.test("45cbc4a0e4123f6920000002"); // => true
```

My use case is that I am working with a set of hex strings and would like to only validate as true those that are mongodb objectIDs.

Comment: `112345679065574883030833`, `FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` are also  valid hexadecimal representations. Why `false` for those strings?

Comment: @falsetru As per my use case, I need a regex that will only match mongodb ObjectIDs.

Comment: As answerd by @olegshparber all the above IDs form a valid mongodb object ID please refer to mongodb Object ID documentation

Comment: @gabeno I still don't understand what you're trying to do as all three are valid MongoDB ObjectIDs.

Comment: He wants to match MongoDB ObjectIDs in practice, not in theory.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

You can use following regular expression **but it will not quite work**

```
checkForHexRegExp = /^(?=[a-f\d]{24}$)(\d+[a-f]|[a-f]+\d)/i
```

Example:

```
> checkForHexRegExp.test("112345679065574883030833")
false
> checkForHexRegExp.test("FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF")
false
> checkForHexRegExp.test("45cbc4a0e4123f6920000002")
true
```

But, as I commented, `112345679065574883030833`, `FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` are also valid hexadecimal representations.

**You should use** `/^[a-f\d]{24}$/i` because it passes all the above tests

Comment: is `i` flag required?

Comment: @transang, Yes it is. (to ignore case)

Comment: It could be removed though, but that'd make the regex itself longer `/^[a-fA-F\d]{24}$/`. Not sure what the performance impact is, but I assume if there is one, it'll be minimal (at least in this case)

Comment: ObjectId.TryParse returns true for "FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF"

Comment: @KishanVaishnav, I don't know what `TryParse` is. I think it's not a javascript method. (This question is tagged javascript). How about post a separate question?

Comment: Sorry, it is a C# method. I just wanted to assert that the Mongo Driver seem to think that it is a valid ObjectId.

Answer (score 25):

> I need a regex that will only match mongodb ObjectIDs

If you need that, you will have to specify exactly what makes up a mongodb ObjectID, so that we can create the appropriate regex string for it.

---

This should technically work in js:

```
var myregexp = /^[0-9a-fA-F]{24}$/;
subject = "112345679065574883030833";

if (subject.match(myregexp)) {
    // Successful match
} else {
    // Match attempt failed
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Technically, all examples in the question potentially could be valid ObjectIds. If you have to add some additional verification and that regexp is not enough, then my suggestion is to check if the first 4 bytes are a valid timestamp. You can even verify that ObjectId has been generated during a certain period of time (e.g. since your project has been started or so). See [ObjectId documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/) for details.

If there's another timestamp field in an object, then it's also possible to make sure that both times are really close.

Just for the reference, in MongoDB shell [ObjectId::getTimestamp()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/ObjectId.getTimestamp/#ObjectId.getTimestamp) method can be used to extract a timestamp from ObjectId.

Answer (score 3):

I would do something like this

```
function validateObjectId(id)
{
    var bool=false; 
    if(id.length==24) bool=/[a-f]+/.test(id);
    return bool;
}


> validateObjectId("112345679065574883030833")
  false
> validateObjectId("FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF")
  false
> validateObjectId("45cbc4a0e4123f6920000002")
  true
> validateObjectId("45cbc4a0e4123f6920")
  false
```

Comment: `validateObjectId("ffffffffffffffffffffffff")` returns `true`

Answer (score 0):

For those who was looking just for hex checking the string:

```
s := "5fa0ef460c2056137465a39b"
if _, err := hex.DecodeString(s); err == nil {
    fmt.Println("ok")
}
```