# multiple routes with differents params, calling the same ressource

Tags: node.js, rest, express, mongoose

Is it possible with expressjs to have multiple routes calling the same resource, something like that:

```
app.get('/users/:user_id', users.getOne)
app.get('/users/:username', users.getOne)
```

I would like to be able to call users.getOne whichever params (:user_id or :username) is used in the get request.

In the users.getOne function, how can I determine wich one was used and build my query according to it?

```
exports.getOne = function(req, res){

  var queryParams = ? // I need help here

  Users
    .find(queryParams)
    ...
```

Thanks!

Possibly related: [express.js - single routing handler for multiple routes in a single line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15350025/multiple-routes-single-function-call-express-js)

Comment: What if someone picks a username that collides with one of your user IDs?

Comment: Username are limited to 16 chars. whereas user_id is a mongoDB  generated hash wish is 24 chars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Those are in fact, from express's view, the same route.

No, they are not. One route has `:user_id` parameter, another one has `:username`.

This would be a proper solution:

```
var OBJECT_ID_RE = /^[a-f\d]{24}$/i;

app.param('user_id', function(req, res, next, value, name) {
  if (OBJECT_ID_RE.test(value)) {
    next()
  } else {
    next('route')
  }
})

app.get('/users/:user_id', users.getOne)
app.get('/users/:username', users.getOne)
```

`app.param` set the prerequisite for the route to be called. This way when user_id matches a pattern, first route gets called, otherwise second one.

Comment: OK, to clarify, they both match the same URLs, thus the need for `next('route')` which IMHO is a code smell that maybe you are trying to be overly fancy with your routing. I'm not a fan of fancy routing. I like dead simple, obvious, non-magic, easy-to-debug, routing. That said, your solution is indeed nicely idiomatic for express.

Comment: `next('route')` is a standard way of ignoring the particular route in the middleware. Only disadvantage is that calls depend on ordering, but it can be fixed easily.

Answer (score 4):

From express's view, both of those routes will match the same set of request URLs. You only need one of them and you can name it to make more sense:

```
app.get('/users/:key', users.getOne);

//...
// http://stackoverflow.com/a/20988824/266795
var OBJECT_ID_RE = /^[a-f\d]{24}$/i;
exports.getOne = function(req, res) {
  var conditions = {_id: req.params.key};
  if (!OBJECT_ID_RE.test(req.params.key)) {
    conditions = {username: req.params.key};
  }
  Users.find(conditions)...
```

If you end up wanting this pattern in many routes throughout your code base, you can extract it into a `/users/:user` param and use `app.param` as per @alex's answer, but encapsulate the code to locate the user and stick it on to `req.user` so the actual route handler can just assume the user has been properly found and loaded by the time it executes, and 404 handling can be centralized as well.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, it's working, but I'm wondering if a completely different workaround exist. I mean, at first, am I approaching the problem the right way? Is that a think to do? What would you really do if you wanted to achieve something like that?

Comment: @inwpitrust no, creating the exact same route twice is not the correct approach. Peter shows a good way.

Comment: Yes, no I mean, forget my code, but when designing a RESTful API, is Peter's solution the way you would tackle this problem ? Retrieving user's data by :id or :username, do you think I should enable this feature ?

Comment: RESTful means IDs go in the URL, not usernames. But I don't hesitate to violate REST conventions because I personally think they are meh at best. Looking stuff up by other fields is a search and that should use the query string IMHO but I'm old school in that I think the query string is actually a good idea and I don't feel compelled to reimplement it as URL path parameters to make my URLs "clean".