# MongoDB $regex with $in clause

Tags: mongodb, vert.x

I need a mongodb query something like

```
db.getCollection("xyz").find({"_id" :  {$regex : {$in : [xxxx/*]}}})
```

My Use case is -- I have a list of Strings such as

```
[xyz/12/poi, abc/98/mnb, ytn/65/tdx, ...]
```

The ids that are there in the collection(test) are something like

```
xyz/12/poi/2019061304.
```

I will get the values like `xyz/12/poi` from the input list, the other part of the id being `yyyymmddhh` format.

So, I need to go to the collection and find all the documents matching the input list with the ID of the documents in the test collection.

I can retrieve the documents individually but that does not seem to be a feasible option as the size of the input list is more than 10000.

Can you guys suggest a more feasible solution. Thanks in advance.

I tried using $in with $regex. But it seems mongodb does not support that. I have also tried pattern matching but even that is not feasible for me. Can you please suggest an alternative to using $in with $regex in mongodb.

Expected result could be an aggragate query/a normal query so that we hit the database only once and get the desired output rather than hitting the db for 10000 odd times.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not sure I understood you. You want to use $regex with a set of different regex, so you said to use $in, right?

Comment: I want to use $regex for a list of input. $regex is only for a single element in a json object, but I have a list of input and for each input, I need to use regex.

Comment: And you couldn't combine the text of the inputs in the same regex? For example, and simplifying it a lot, if in the inputs are the values "a" and "b", the query would be `db.getCollection("xyz").find({"_id" : {$regex: /a|b/}})`

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed that you want to use `$regex`  on `_id` and I don't think that's possible. The `_id` field is not a string, it's an `ObjectId`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29568350/query-mongodb-with-a-regex-expression-against-an-objectid

Comment: In my case, the _id is a String of the format - xyz/123/qwe/yyyymmddhh. I just want to use $regex on a list of Strings(this could be anything). I cannot use pattern matching of mongodb as well. Is there a way we can write an aggregate query for the same ? I am new to MongoDB so it is getting difficult for me to understand.