# Regex matching strings that are not a valid mongo id

Tags: javascript, python, regex, mongodb

[In other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20988824/2710757) they explain how to match a MongoDB object id through a regex. I am looking the opposite: given a string, a regex that returns positive if it *is not* a valid mongo object id. In other words, I want to match everything that is not a mongodb object id.

I suppose it should be as easy as negate (?!) the regex, but I am not capable of making it right.

The regex should work in Javascript and Python3 (it could be two different regexs). I can accept a small loss of precision, if needed, and the string can have space but not newlines.

For example, a full name (`James Bond`) should match positive, but not (`45cbc4a0e4123f6920000002`)

[More about Mongodb object Ids](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#objectid).

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

This might be it:

```js
const isNotMongoObject = id => !/^(?=[a-f\d]{24}$)(\d+[a-f]|[a-f]+\d)/i.test(id)

const testIds = [" James Bond ", "45cbc4a0e4123f6920000002", "112345679065574883030833", "FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF", "45cbc4a0e4123f6920000002", ` James 
Bond `]
for (const id of testIds) {
  console.log(`${id} ${isNotMongoObject(id)}`)  
}
```

```
def isNotMongoObject id:
    return re.match(r"^(?=[a-f\d]{24}$)(\d+[a-f]|[a-f]+\d)", id) is not None
```

Answer (score 0):

In regex language, the opposite would be:

```
^(?!(?=[a-f\d]{24}$)(\d+[a-f]|[a-f]+\d)).+
```

Which yields the following results:

```
112345679065574883030833 => true
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF => true
45cbc4a0e4123f6920000002 => false (ie a mongo id)
112345679065574883030833 => true
James Bond => true
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/Bzafue/1).
Another (better?) way would be to prove if it **is** a Mongo ID and then check the negation programmatically.