# How to check if string is of type ObjectId in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have a route `/api/:id` where :id has to be of type ObjectId.
Because following is the query I am runnuing

```js
const data = await Person.find({_id:req.params.id})
```

It works fine if :id is of type `ObjectId` but if user explicitly runs the api lets say `/api/anything`, then Mongoose throughs an error

> CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "anything" at path "_id"

So, I would like to check if `req.params.id` is of type `ObjectId` and perform further operations only if it is.

Thus code would look like

```js
if(checkObjectId(req.params.id)) {
const data = await Person.find({_id:req.params.id})
}
```

Comment: Maybe this will help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13850819/can-i-determine-if-a-string-is-a-mongodb-objectid

Comment: I'd combine the express param regex validation (e.g. `/api/:id(\d+)`) with a good regex that matches the ObjectId, e.g `[a-f\d]{24}` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20988446/regex-for-mongodb-objectid). That would mean `api/:id([a-f\d]{24})` should do here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Mongoose functionality:

```
if(mongoose.isValidObjectId(req.params.id)) {
  const data = await Person.find({_id:req.params.id})
  ...
}
```

> ### [`Mongoose.prototype.isValidObjectId()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/mongoose.html#mongoose_Mongoose-isValidObjectId)
>
> Returns true if Mongoose can cast the given value to an ObjectId, or
> false otherwise.
>
> ```
> mongoose.isValidObjectId(new mongoose.Types.ObjectId()); // true
> mongoose.isValidObjectId('0123456789ab'); // true
> mongoose.isValidObjectId(6); // false
> ```

Answer (score 2):

you can use isValid method for validate object id

> mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid('63d632828e944c3a08f15925')

Answer (score 0):

Why `if` when you can use `try ... catch`

```
let data;
try {
    data = await Person.find({_id:req.params.id})
} catch(err) {
    console.log('Error retrieving data (Person):', err);
}
```

Comment: Thats not the way of checking :)