# System.FormatException' occurred in MongoDB.Bson.dll - XXX is not a valid 24 digit hex string

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have created a C# class like this:

```
 public class Employee
    {
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public List<string> Address { get; set; }
    }
```

When I try to save this information (using MongoDB) like this:

```
   var e = new Employee();
    e.Address = new List<string>();
    e.Address.Add("Address 1");
    e.Address.Add("Address 2");

    e.Age = 333;
    e.Name = "Some Name";

   context.Employees.Insert(e);
```

**I am getting following error:**

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in MongoDB.Bson.dll

Additional information: 'Some Name' is not a valid 24 digit hex string.
```

How can I make a string field to act as `ObjectID` in MongoDB?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Reading from the docs:

> ... In this case the serializer will convert the ObjectId to a string when
>   reading data from the database and will convert the string back to an
>   ObjectId when writing data to the database (**the string value must be a
>   valid ObjectId**) ....

Please remove the white space from your string. Than everything should work!

To proof wether you have a valid ObjectId, read the following SO-Post: [MongoDB Node check if objectid is valid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11989159/2630261)

**EDIT**:
the final answer was: `You have to change [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)] to [BsonId]`

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. I removed the white space and changed the code to `e.Name = "SomeName";`, but still I am getting the same error.

Comment: @SharpCoder What habbens when you change `[BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]` to `[BsonId]`?

Comment: Yes. That helps !!! adding `[BsonId]` attribute instead of `[BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]` over `userId` property resolved the issue. Can you please update your answer, this will help some other user in future!! Thanks !!

Comment: @SharpCoder ok, perfect!

Comment: So I'm getting this error on my ID but I'm using an MD5 hash which is too long. Do you know of a work around, or do I need some other type of hashing algorithm that ensures < 24 digits?

Comment: I figured it out. I just changed the field to type `String` instead of `ObjectId`. Which is in a round-about way exactly what your answer said.

Answer (score 3):

A valid ObjectId string type has a 12bytes hex string like `'546c776b3e23f5f2ebdd3b03'`.

You put `[BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]` for your Property `Name`. that means c# driver convert a string to ObjectId and vise-versa automatically before any serialization operation.

Remove `[BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]` and

if you register `BsonSerializer.RegisterIdGenerator(typeof(string), new StringObjectIdGenerator())` at your app start up,
and if you have a property named `Id` for your entity, mongo put string instead of ObjectId for Id fields, and you can use any string as key for `Id` fields.