# MongoDB - findOne using the params id results in an empty object or an error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm learning Express/Mongo(using mLab) by building a simple little app that I can create a list of clients and a single client detail page.

**localhost:3000/clients** renders the entire collection of '*clients*'

**localhost:3000/clients/:id** should render the specific client by id

This is a collection: *clients* entry example from MongoDB (mLab):

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "57ba01d3ab462a0aeec66646"
    },
    "name": "ClientName",
    "address": {
        "street": "StreetName",
        "city": "Cityname",
        "state": "Statename",
        "zip": "1234"
    },
    "createDate": {
        "$date": "2016-08-21T19:32:35.525Z"
    }
}
```

I successfully created an href on the **/clients** page with the id value that links to the specific client:

```
<a href="/clients/<%= client._id %>"><%= client.name %></a>
```

Which correctly results in this:

```
http://localhost:3000/clients/57ba01d3ab462a0aeec66646
```

Here is my get function for **/clients/:id**:

```
app.get('/clients/:id', (req, res) => {
  db.collection('clients').findOne(req.params.id, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      handleError(res, err.message, "Failed to get clients.");
    } else {
      console.log(result);
      res.render('client.ejs', {client: result})
    }
  });
})
```

Clicking on the link results in the following error:

> MongoError: query selector must be an object at
>   Function.MongoError.create
>   (/Users/username/Desktop/node/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/error.js:31:11)
>   at Collection.find
>   [...]

I've been reading and searching all afternoon and trying a ton of different options like:

- 'You need to create an ObjectID': https://stackoverflow.com/a/10929670
- 'You need to use Mongoose to create the ObjectID': https://stackoverflow.com/a/30652361

Do I really need Mongoose? This seems like a foundational thing to do it Mongo — why isn't it working?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB $oid vs ObjectId](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26938598/mongodb-oid-vs-objectid)

Comment: That may be a duplicate, but since I don't know wtf I'm doing, I'm not familiar with the query on that question being in the form of json: `{
    "_id": {
        "$in": [
            {
                "$oid": "54651022bffebc03098b4567"
            },
            {
                "$oid": "54651022bffebc03098b4568"
            }
        ]
   }
}`

Comment: Your filter criteria should be: *{"_id": { "$oid": req.params.id}}*. The issue is you're using *$oid* instead of normal plain *ObjectId*.

Comment: It's slowly sinking in :/ . However, when I add what you outlined, I get a hard err: `db.collection('clients').findOne({"_id": { "$oid": req.params.id}}, (err, result) => {[...]`

Comment: ^ That results in: `{"error":"Failed to get clients."}`

Comment: Ok, sorry I forgot you should wrap your *res.params.id* with *mongo.ObjectId()* like: *mongo.ObjectId(res.params.id)*. Where *mongo* is the variable name of MongoDB package.

Comment: That didn't seem to work. I ended up following this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10929670/6286756 and stripping back out the inner {$oid: req.params.id}. This works: `var oi = new require('mongodb').ObjectID(req.params.id);
  db.collection('clients').findOne({"_id": oi}, (err, result) => {`

Comment: Please write the answer as a post.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use an object : `{id: req.params.id}`

```
app.get('/clients/:id', (req, res) => {
  db.collection('clients').findOne({_id: req.params.id}, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      handleError(res, err.message, "Failed to get clients.");
    } else {
      console.log(result);
      res.render('client.ejs', {client: result})
    }
  });
})
```

Comment: I had this at one point and while it no longer gives me the object error, I get a different error when trying to access the client.name on the page: `<%= client.name %>` The error I get is: `TypeError: client.ejs:16
   14| 
   15| 
>> 16|   <%= client.name %>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert req.params.id to MongoObject and then use it:

var id = new ObjectID(req.params.id);

Comment: I tried this, but I get the following error : ReferenceError: ObjectID is not defined

Comment: You should write this before using it
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
 db.collection('clients').findOne({"_id.$oid": req.params.id}, (err, result) =>
```