# Validate MongoDB ObjectId

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Is there a way to validate a MongoDB **ObjectId** without actually hitting the MongoDB database at all? For example, the string value `"5c0a7922c9d89830f4911426"` should result in `"true"`.

Comment: Can you explain if you want to know if the ObjectId actually _exists_, or is it okay for you if it just a potential valid ObjectId string? Because in the latter case the answers here might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985228/mongodb-node-check-if-objectid-is-valid

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use [.isValid()](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/objectid.html#objectid-isvalid) method on ObjectId, try in mongoose:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var isValid = mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid('5c0a7922c9d89830f4911426'); //true
```

Comment: what happened if I pass a stirng with the length of 12? `var isValid = mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid('lkjyuhgfdres')`

Comment: @SudarshanaDayananda of course it cannot be valid since it contains non-hexadecimal characters

Comment: but in the question there is nothing about hexadecimal/non-hexadecimal. It is about validating any string whether it is valid MongoDB id or not

Comment: @SudarshanaDayananda A valid MongoDB ObjectID only contains hexadecimal characters. So a string like "lkjyuhgfdres" is obviously not a valid ObjectID. Also be aware of that this only validates that the id is VALID, not if it EXISTS inside a database.

Comment: any 12 char string passes this

Comment: @TusharShahi yes you are correct; I suggest use this small npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/joi-objectid

Answer (score 7):

Please note that in almost all scenarios you just have to handle the `catch` and not bother with the validity of the `ObjectID` since mongoose would complain `throw` if invalid `ObjectId` is provided.

```
Model.findOne({ _id: 'abcd' }).exec().catch(error => console.error('error', error));
```

Other than that you could either use the [mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/objectid.html#objectid-isvalid) or a regular expression: `/^[a-fA-F0-9]{24}$/`

Answer (score 2):

@mickl's Answer will be failed for the strings with the length of 12.

You should convert any given string to **`MongoDB`** **`ObjectId`** using **`ObjectId`** constructor in **`mongodb`** and then cast it to a string and the check again with the original one. It should be the same.

```
  import { ObjectId } from 'mongodb'

  function isValidId(id) {

     return new ObjectId(id).toString() === id;
  }

  isValidId('5c0a7922c9d89830f4911426')// true
  isValidId('lkjyuhgfdres')// false
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, it crashes the mongodb client with the same error of "Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters".

Comment: Wrap it in a trycatch? try returns true, catch returns false...

Answer (score 0):

The API provided ([Mongoose.prototype.isValidObjectId()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/mongoose.html#mongoose_Mongoose-isValidObjectId) and for newer versions and ) returns true for random strings like `Manajemenfs2`.

With mongoose this is how I ended up doing it:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';


const isValidMongoId = (id: string) => {  
  try {
    const objectID = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id);
    const objectIDString = objectID.toString();
    return objectIDString === id;
  } catch (e){
    return false;
  } 
};
```

The definition of the method clearly shows:

```
Mongoose.prototype.isValidObjectId = function(v) {
  if (v == null) {
    return true;
  }

  //Other code

  if (v.toString instanceof Function) {
    v = v.toString();
  }

  if (typeof v === 'string' && v.length === 12) {
    return true;
  }

  //Other code

  return false;
};
```

that for general primitive strings and even string objects, any string of length 12 passes.

Answer (score 0):

```
let mongoose = require('mongoose'); 
let ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId; 
let recId1 = "621f1d71aec9313aa2b9074c"; 
let isValid1 = ObjectId.isValid(recId1); //true 
console.log("isValid1 = ", isValid1); //true 
let recId2 = "621f1d71aec9313aa2b9074cd"; 
let isValid2 = ObjectId.isValid(recId2); //false
console.log("isValid2 = ", isValid2); //false
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you use **Joi** for validating, you can include validation directly in your **Joi schemas**, using **[joi-objectid](https://github.com/pebble/joi-objectid)**:

Install joi-objectid: `$ npm i joi-objectid`

Define the function to use globally (with Joi already imported):

```
Joi.objectId = require('joi-objectid')(Joi)
```

Use it in your Joi schema:

```js
function validateUser(user) {
    const schema = {
        userId: Joi.objectId().required(),
        name: Joi.string().required()
    };
    return Joi.validate(user, schema);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an inbuilt function in mongoose

```
import { isValidObjectId } from "mongoose";

const isIDValid = isValidObjectId(id);

if (!isIDValid) throw { message: `Invalid ID provided` };
```