# Why does lodash consider a mongoose object id as empty when it did not before?

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose, lodash

Example would be:

```js
const objectId = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId('id would go here');
  if (_.isEmpty(objectId)) {
    throw new Error('this throws an error');
  }
```

ran code above and was just wondering if this is new, for what its worth, this code did not break before.

Comment: Not sure why, but to validate, I'd use `ObjectId.isValid`. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25497438/298455

Answer (score 0):

Using the following code:

```
const _ = require("lodash");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const objectId = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId('deadcaffee00deadbeef1122');

const isEmpty = _.isEmpty(objectId);

console.log("keys", Object.keys(objectId));
for (let i in objectId) {
    console.log("property", i, objectId[i]);
}

console.log({ objectId, isEmpty });
```

You can see that `objectId` only contains one property that whose key is a `Symbol`.

You'll note that it isn't logged as a property (only `valueOf` is logged), and that the keys array is empty.

Looking at [the source code](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.17.15/lodash.js#L11479) you'll see it iterates over the keys using a for-in loop just as I did to log the properties.

Since we have no properties to log that satisfies `hasOwnProperty`, then the loop ends and it returns `true`.